# Reaching accessibility hierarchy in Google Chrome on OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, accessibility

For some reason Google Chrome doesn't return accessibility nodes from scroll areas of its tabs, i.e. accessible information of any web page content.

Is it possible to turn it on somewhere or Chrome simply doesn't support accessibility?

[image: Chrome]

Safari does great:

[image: Safari]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it's really easy but hidden deep inside the Chromium wiki: `chrome://accessibility`